# Какой самый простой способ сделать двуязычный сайт?

Tags: php, mysql

Вот что я нагуглил. Видел такие варианты есть сайт site.com/en или site.com/ru т.е. я выбрал язык, например русский, и если я перейду на страницу о нас то будет что то типа того site.com/ru/o_nas если на английский то site.com/en/o_nas т.е. есть страница en и ru и через них это работает.
Также видел такое index.php?lang-en или index.php?lang-ru, эти get параметры дописываются при нажатии на выбор языка и допустим главная перевелась, хотя у меня пока не получилось. но если перейти на site.com/o_nas то эти get параметры пропадают. 
Мне нужно что бы при нажатии на en|ru соответственно сайт перевился полностью и на какую я страницу бы не перешел она была на выбранном языке. На счет куки и сессий, они не важны сейчас, главное что бы пока не закрыт браузер язык оставался выбранным, пока пользователь сам не переключит на другой.

ООП и подобного не нужно, самое простое на процедурном.

У меня все берется с БД как я понял если 2 языка то нужно создать по 2 таблицы o_nas_ru и o_nas_en и при условии писать в нужную. Но на практике не выходит.

блок для переключение языка.

```
<div class="tag">Language:<a href="index.php?lang-en">English</a>|<a href="index.php?lang=ru">Русский</div>
```

Как сделать то что я описал выше, и что бы нужный текст с админки писался в нужную таблицу (в админке будет сразу два поля например для русского и анг. текста и в БД разные таблицы) и отображался в зависимости от того что выбрано на сайте ru или en? Можно небольшой пример для понимания сути.

И как сделать что бы по стандарту был русский, т.е. что бы не просто index.php грузится в index.php.ru или index.php?lang.ru как правильней?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте представим, что язык на сайте переключается при помощи GET-переменной lang. Тогда где-то в начале скрипта нужно выполнить проверку выбора языка:

```
$lang = 'ru'; // Язык по умолчанию
$available_lang = ['ru', 'en'];
if (isset($_GET['lang']) AND in_array($_GET['lang'], $available_lang, true)) {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
}
```

Теперь префикс $lang можно подставлять для генерации названий страниц для загрузки ($name_page = 'o_nas_'.$lang;). В каждую ссылку также нужно добавлять префикс языка, чтобы не потерять выбор пользователя.

Советую вам также обратить внимание на "единую точку входа" - подробнее смотрите в Гугле. В этом случае все запросы к сайту можно будет обрабатывать в одном скрипте.

P.S. Для любителей вносить правки в ответ без проверки: строка $available_lang = {'ru', 'en'}; - некорректный код на PHP, массив можно инициализировать либо так: $available_lang = ['ru', 'en']; либо так: $available_lang = array('ru', 'en'); Просьба не вносить ошибочные правки в мой ответ. Пользователь Deonis в комментариях к ответу разместил ссылку на документацию по PHP: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php#example-99 где можно посмотреть, как инициализируются массивы в PHP.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. А какие есть еще варианты мультиязычности кроме get параметров?

Comment: парсер говорит что синтаксическая ошибка в этой строке $available_lang = ['ru', 'en'];

Comment: @АртурЧерешнюк парсер умалчивает, что у вас древняя версия PHP (*не выше 5.4*) и [подобный синтаксис](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php#example-99) объявления массивов не поддерживает.

Comment: Замените строку на $available_lang = array('ru', 'en'); хотя, лучше не использовать древний PHP, и обновиться до новой актуальной версии 5.6, а лучше 7.0

Comment: Можно придумать еще много вариантов, как сделать мультиязычный сайт, кроме как с помощью GET/URL, но учтите, что в таком случае поисковые системы могут забраковать/плохо индексировать сайт.

Comment: А какой нормальный вариант с точки зрения СЕО?

Comment: Чтобы поисковые системы правильно индексировали сайт, нужно, чтобы каждая уникальная страница имела свой уникальный url. Соответственно каждая языковая версия, одной и той же страницы должна также иметь свой уникальный url. Например: русский вариант страницы о нас - site.com/onas.php, английский -site.com/onas.php?lang=en или site.com/en/onas.php. Если сделать единую точку входа и добавить ЧПУ в htaccess, то адреса url могут выглядеть как-то так: site.com/onas/ и site.com/en/onas/